# Ansible "log_path=/var/log/ansible.log" Maximum number of Files & size

Tags: ansible

I am trying to find, what is default maximum file size of log file "ansible.log". Config file only explain its logrotate so what are the maximum number of files are generated and maximum size of these files. Or is it just a one single file and logrotate after some specific size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible use Python module [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#module-logging) which does not take care of log-rotation. It is possible to [rotate logs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-file-rotation) in Python, but only 2 Ansible modules use the Pyhton module [logging.handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#module-logging.handlers)

(grep git repo)

```
$ grep -ri logging.handlers  /devel/ansible/
/scratch/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/syslog_json.py:import logging.handlers
/scratch/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/syslog_json.py:        self.handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(
/scratch/ansible/lib/ansible/module_utils/network/avi/avi_api.py:    from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
```

and no module use the [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler)

```
$ grep -ri RotatingFileHandler  /devel/ansible/
```

But, it's not that difficult to configure the rotation. For example, take a look at [logrotate.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-linux-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/logrotate.yml) from the role [linux_postinstall](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/linux_postinstall).